# Embedding power bi reports in cordova apps

Tags: cordova, powerbi-embedded

I am trying power bi embedded to embed reports in my cordova app following this tutorial 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-iframe/

and i generate the access tokens and get other details using PowerBI-Node SDK
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Node

the reports are working fine if the run the app in browser but not in mobile. I am getting

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
  "https://embedded.powerbi.com" from accessing a frame with origin
  "file://".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", 
  the frame being accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match
```

Is there any workaround. I have tried adding `<access origin="*"/>.` in my config file also.